# Truncating HTML in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, truncate

I am looking to truncate the html on my index page by 100 characters and use a trailing "..." and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do that. Right now, I'm trying to use the package, [nodejs-html-truncate](https://github.com/huang47/nodejs-html-truncate), but running into an issue using it. The documentation isn't very clear, at least to me, and I'm calling it within my routes file, but not sure how to truncate within my ejs file. I'm only getting errors. Is there a better package or method to truncate? or is there a clear mistake that I am making when using this package?

routes.js (route('/') is where I am calling the truncate variable)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
var paginate = require('express-paginate');
var truncate = require('html-truncate');

//index 
router.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));

    router.route('/') 

        // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // set the tags
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: 'Blog created.' });
                });

        }) // END POST method


        // START GET method
        .get(function(req, res, next) {

            Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {




                if (err) return next(err)

                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);


                        blogpost.title = req.body.title; // get the blog title
                        blogpost.author = req.body.author; // get the author name
                        blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // get tagline
                        blogpost.content = req.body.content; // get the blog content
                        blogpost.category = req.body.category; // get the category
                        blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // get the tags
                        blogpost.date = req.body.date; // get the date of the post


                        res.format({
                            html: function() {
                                res.render('pages/index', {
                                    blogpost: blogpost,
                                    pageCount: pageCount,
                                    itemCount: itemCount,
                                    truncate: truncate
                                })
                            },
                            json: function() {

                                res.json({
                                    object: 'blogpost',
                                    has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                                    data: blogpost
                                })
                            }
                        }); // END res.format(html, json)
            }); // END Blogpost.paginate
        }); // END GET method


    //Route for individual blogs
    router.route('/blog/:blogpost_id')


    // START GET method blog by ID  
    .get(function(req, res) {



        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blogpost) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);


            //res.json(blogpost);
            res.render('pages/blogpost', {
                blogpost: blogpost
            });
        });
    }) // END GET method blog by ID

    // START PUT method
    .put(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blogpost) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);


            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // update the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // update the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // update the category 
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; //update the tags
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // update the date of the post


            blogpost.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);


                res.json({ message: 'Blog updated.' });
            });

        });

    }) // END PUT method

    // START DELETE method
    .delete(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.remove({
            _id: req.params.blogpost_id

        }, function(err, bear) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });



//about
    router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/about');
    });

//resume
    router.get('/resume', function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/resume');
    });



module.exports = router;
```

index.ejs (I am trying to use this method for blog.content)

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-9-12">
            <div class="blog-content">
                <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2><a href="#" class="blog-title"><%= blogpost.title %></a></h2></td>
                        <td><h3><%= blogpost.date %></h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-category"><%= blogpost.category %></h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-tagline"><i><%= blogpost.tagline %></i></h3></td>
                        <td><p><%= blogpost.content.truncate(100) %></p></td>
                        <td><a href="/blog/<%= blogpost.id %>" class="blog-read-more">Read More</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3-12">
            <div class="sidebar-personal-information">
                <div id="sidebar-social-media">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img class="sidebar-social-media-icons" src="images/linkedin.png"></li>
                        <li><img class="sidebar-social-media-icons" src="images/twitter.png"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar-current-titles">
                    <h3>####</h3>
                    <h4><a href="#">#####</a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar-short-summary">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a massa ante. Vestibulum eu enim est. Curabitur a leo venenatis, semper tellus ac, venenatis nisi. Fusce magna urna, cursus quis egestas et, tincidunt ut nisi. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent congue nec lectus vel posuere.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-newsletter-signup">
                <h3>NEWSLETTER</h3>
                <form>
                    <input type="email"></input>
                    <br>
                    <input id="email-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="paginate">
        <% include ../partials/paginate %>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope you realize that an HTML stream can't just be chopped anywhere and still be valid.

Comment: Hey @jfriend00, I have tried the example in the documentation and wrapped the elements that need to be truncated, but no success and I understand that the approach in my post doesn't make sense, but this is the point where I last gave it a shot and is why it is in this state.